# Why my object Triggering too far?

Tags: unity

I have some issues with detecting the collision when OnTrigger2d, as you can see in my screenshot below, that actually too far from the object.

[image: this is my rigidbody setting]

[image]

this my script

````cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isDeath", true);

            _GameManager.instance.GameOver();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isDeath", false);

        }
    }
```
````

Comment: Consider using a box collider. Polygon collider are not offering that much more but are taking way more computing power. And it does not even looks like it covers your dino correctly. You can as well use 2 box colliders on the dino if you feel like the head should deserve its own for narrow dodges on the feet.

Comment: From the inspector it looks both the dino and the cacti is selected.

Comment: I would approach this problem by setting a Visual Studio debugger breakpoint in the OnTriggerEnter2D method, wait for it to trigger and then take a look at the local variables to find out what exactly collides with what and where. Can you do that?